# Merge 2 queries in 1 Doctrine DQL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine 2.4 with Symfony 2.8 and I'm trying to build a friendship system.

I have my MateRelationship entity :

```
class MateRelationship
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sender", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     *
     */
    private $sender;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="receiver", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     *
     */
    private $receiver;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $invitationAccepted;
```

My goal is to make a DQL query to get all accepted friends relationship for a given user (no matter if the user is sender or receiver) .

I managed to do it with 2 queries and by merging results, but it's not optimized and it's harder to implement `$limit` this way.

```
public function getMates($user, $limit = 0){

    $query1 = $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT m, u.nickname, u.username FROM AcmeUserBundle:MateRelationship m JOIN m.receiver u WHERE m.invitationAccepted = 1 AND m.sender = :user')
            ->setParameter('user', $user);

    try{
        $result1 = $query1->getResult();
    }
    catch(\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e){
        $result1 = [];
    }

    $query2 = $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT m, u.nickname, u.username FROM AcmeUserBundle:MateRelationship m JOIN m.sender u WHERE m.invitationAccepted = 1 AND m.receiver = :user')
            ->setParameter('user', $user);

    try{
        $result2 = $query2->getResult();
    }
    catch(\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e){
        $result2 = [];
    }

    return array_merge($result1, $result2);
}
```

I'd like to have a single query so I could use `->setMaxResults($limit)` but I have no idea how to merge these 2 queries in 1. 
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a proposal using the doctrine query builder

```
public function getMates($user, $limit = 0)
{
    // Create query builder
    $queryBuilder = $this->_em->getRepository("AcmeUserBundle:MateRelationship")->createQueryBuilder('m');

    // Create 'or' expression
    $or = $queryBuilder->expr()->orX();
    $or
        ->add('m.sender = :user')
        ->add('m.receiver = :user');

    // Create the query
    $queryBuilder
        ->andWhere('m.invitationAccepted = 1')
        ->andWhere($or)
        ->setMaxResults($limit)
        ->setParameter('user', $user);

    // Return the result
    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `LEFT JOIN` and `CASE` to obtain the valid user information:

```
    public function getMates($user, $limit = 0)
    {
        $dql = <<<DQL
            SELECT 
               m, 
               CASE usen.nickname IS NULL WHEN TRUE THEN urec.nickname ELSE usen.nickname END AS nickname, 
               CASE usen.username IS NULL WHEN TRUE THEN urec.username ELSE usen.username END AS username, 
               CASE usen.nickname IS NULL WHEN TRUE THEN 'sender' ELSE 'receiver' END AS relationship
            FROM AcmeUserBundle:MateRelationship m 
            LEFT JOIN m.sender usen 
            LEFT JOIN m.receiver urec 
            WHERE m.invitationAccepted = 1 AND (m.receiver = :user OR m.sender= :user)
DQL;

        return $this->_em->createQuery($dql)
            ->setParameter('user', $user)
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->getResult();
    }
```

If the `$result` is empty it's already an empty array `[]`.

**Note:** The `NoResultException` exception only is thrown for `getOneOrNullResult`, `getSingleResult` or `getSingleScalarResult` methods they are invoked.

Comment: I've updated the answer using alias for `CASE` statements, it's a little easier to extract data.

Comment: It seems really good, but doctrine throws an exception

`"Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException"
"[Syntax Error] line 0, col 32: Error: Unexpected 'NULL'"` could it be related to [this issue](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/3160) ?

Answer (score -2):

You can simply do it by putting `OR` when you match `:user`. That can be either `receiver` OR `sender`.

```
SELECT m, usen.nickname, usen.username, urec.nickname, urec.username
FROM AcmeUserBundle:MateRelationship m 
JOIN m.sender usen 
JOIN m.receiver urec 
WHERE m.invitationAccepted = 1 AND 
(m.receiver = :user OR m.sender= :user)
```

Comment: you need to change `u.` by `usen.` or `urec` alias.

Comment: however it's not so simple, I think. What happen when use `usen.nickname` and `m.sender <> :user` ?

Comment: In this case you need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead `JOIN`, else both `sender` and `receiver` would be equal to `:user` to be selected.

Comment: But then how do you know which one is the friend and which one is the requested user  ?

Comment: You can add another `CASE` to know which user relationship is selected, see my updated above.

Comment: It should work, your motive is to find the friends of the user by either way. So this query should work. The user is the one you're comparing :user